# Retrieve data using between some date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, between

I have the following table in my database

Membership

- ComapanyId
- IsMember
- JoinedDate
- ExpiryDate
- RejoinDate
- LeavingDate

I am using the following query to return all the members as for 2011-01-31

```
select * from MEMBERSHIP 
where (JoinedDate < '2011-01-31' or RejoinDate  < '2011-01-31') and IsMember=1
```

My problem is it doesnt tally with the figures my manager has. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: An you explain the relationship between `joineddate`, `expirydate`, `rejoindate` and `leavingdate`.  And also what `ismember` means?

Comment: You're being too vague.  For `ismember` does it mean that they're a member ***today*** and so means ***nothing*** for a historical date?  You need to be complete, and precise, about all those fields so that we can understand all of the use cases.

Comment: @dems Member as of today. Got what I was doing wrong in the following comments. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that IsMember is currently whether they are a member, not whether they were a member on 2011-01-31.  So, your query is really answering the question:  "Which members who were active today joined or last rejoined before 2011-01-31?"

For instance, someone who starts on 2011-01-30 and quits on 2011-02-01 would not count as a member in your query, but would be a member on that date.

The most accurate answer is to look in a transaction table for memberships, where you have joins and quits in the table.

Barring that, the following probably gets close enough:

```
select *
from MEMBERSHIP
where '2011-01-31' between JoinedDate and LeaveDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you remove the "IsMember = 1" statement as you want to list users that were members before 2011-01-31 but are not members anymore? And maybe you should use '<=' if you want to include the 31th.

Also what is the default value of RejoinDate? If it is null it could have an influence on your WHERE statement...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your date is implicitly treated as *midnight* of 2011-01-31 (`'2011-01-31 00:00:00'`), so any activity on that day is not included. Try using `< '2011-02-01'` instead, so that all of the activity on the 31st is included.

Comment: That's just one problem.  I'd presume `IsMember` is a cached value for whether they're a member `today` - So filtering by that for a historic date is a problem.  And just joining before a specific  date is no indicator of whether they left before that date.  And without knowing what all the fields mean, there may be more...

Comment: And the original query is using "<" not "<=", so that seems to be what is intended.

Answer (score 0):

You clould use something like this:

```
JoinedDate <= CONVERT(Date, '2011-01-31')
```

Comment: The OP isn't experiencing a syntax error, just different results.  This won't help at all.